# Custom UIButton layoutSubviews() doesn't work unless super.layoutSubviews() is called

Tags: ios, uibutton

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    var button = CustomButton()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        //add constraints and etc.
    }
}

class CustomButton: UIButton{
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.layer.frame.width * 0.5
        self.setTitle("abc", forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Question 1: how come I have to call `super.layoutSubviews()` for the `setTitle()` to work? (i.e. the `cornerRadius` does get set but not the title)

Question 2: I tried putting the code I have in `layoutSubviews()` in `drawRect()` but that doesn't change the `cornerRadius`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIButton` contains a `UILabel` subviews to display its title. If you don't call `super.layoutSubviews()`, that child label doesn't get set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

UIButton is a UIView, which has its own implementation of `layoutSubviews`.  You still want to make sure that code gets called and hence call `super.layoutSubviews()`. **In addition** to the default implementation (not instead of), you want to set the `cornerRadius` and `title` so you add that code after the call on super.

If you didn't override the method period, `layoutSubviews()` in UIView would be called by default when `layoutIfNeeded` is called.  If you override it and **don't** call `super.layoutSubviews()` then you essentially just removed Apple's implementation of the method.

It's the same reason you should call `super.viewDidLoad()` when overriding a the method inside a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: Rob's answer is correct - because super's implementation isn't called, the UIView doesn't layout its UILabel subview.